# React/redux notifications

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, redux

I'm working on a react/redux project. 
I looking for a component or a package, that displays notification messages to the user, for example [react-notify](https://github.com/k4wo/react-notify).

The components I've found (including react-notify) use refs:

```
<ReactNotify ref='notificator'/>
```

I want a package without refs, if one exists.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I am using react-redux-toastr and it works well for me. It is aesthetically very similar to the demo in react-notify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [redux-notifications](https://github.com/indexiatech/re-notif). It's a pure redux solution without the use of `refs`. The documentation is a bit outdated, but this worked for me (the change is the actions).

You add the `<Notifs />` component to the root of your project:

```
import { Provider }  from 'react-redux'
import { Notifs } from 'redux-notifications';

<Provider store={store}>
  <div>
    // ... other things like router ...
    <Notifs />
  </div>
</Provider>
```

Add the the `notifReducer` to your base reducer:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as notifReducer } from 'redux-notifications';
combineReducers({
  notifs: notifReducer,
  // ... more reducers here ...
})
```

And then use the built in actions to dispatch notifications:

```
import { actions } from 'redux-notifications';

action.notifSend({
    message: "I am a notification",
    kind,
    id: 1234,
    dismissAfter: 2000
})(dispatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently developed a simple library to implement a react-redux notification system on your app and it doesn't need to use ref. Check it out [react-redux-notifications](https://github.com/nicmesan/react-redux-notifications). Any feedback would be appreciate it.